# DATEDIFF between two dates to return timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

**SOLVED**

```
CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,START_DTTM,END_DTTM)/60),'h:',
       (DATEDIFF(Minute,START_DTTM,END_DTTM)%60) 'm') AS TotalTimeMissing
```

Produces TotalTimeMissing: 5h:13m

**________**

I'm trying to return a timestamp value between two specific dates to work out the time between a package going missing and it being found.

*EDIT: Code has been updated to include code from Sami. I have also added additional code that I excluded from the original.*

Here is the current code:

```
USE PACKAGE

GO  

SELECT

        dp.LEGACY_ID

       ,dp.SURNAME

       ,dp.FORENAME

       ,dp.ETHNICITY_DESCRIPTION

       ,dp.BIRTH_DTTM

       ,DATEDIFF(YY, dp.BIRTH_DTTM, GETDATE()) -

            CASE

                  WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 12), 4) >=

                        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), dp.BIRTH_DTTM, 12), 4)

                        THEN 0

                  ELSE 1

            END AS [Current Age]

--^Precise age calc due to potential LL inaccuracy

       ,mp.DIM_PERSON_ID

       ,mp.MISSING_STATUS

       ,mp.START_DTTM

       ,mp.END_DTTM

       ,dp.LEGACY_ID

       ,mp.RETURN_INT_OFFERED

       ,mp.RETURN_INT_ACCEPTED

       ,mp.RETURN_INT_DATE


FROM C_S.FACT_MISSING_PACKAGE AS mp

JOIN C_S.FACT_MISSING_PACKAGE AS dp ON mp.DIM_PERSON_ID = dp.DIM_PERSON_ID

WHERE CAST (mp.START_DTTM AS DATE)

              BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)

--^Displays all records within exactly 1 year of run date

       UNION (SELECT CONCAT(Value / 3600 / 24,

              ' Days ',

              RIGHT(CONCAT('00', Value / 3600 % 24), 2),

              ':',

              RIGHT(CONCAT('00', Value / 60 % 60), 2),

              ':',

              RIGHT(CONCAT('00',Value % 3600 % 60), 2)

       ) AS TotalTimeMissing

FROM

(

  SELECT mp.DIM_PERSON_ID, DATEDIFF(Second, mp.START_DTTM, mp.END_DTTM) Value

  FROM C_S.FACT_MISSING_PACKAGE AS mp

) T(Value))


ORDER BY START_DTTM ASC;
```

Sami got me most of the way there but when I run the above code I get an error in relation to the UNION and T, with T not stating the required number of columns. To solve this I tried putting the initial round of SELECT columns into the (SELECT CONCAT() statement but it generates errors so I'm at a bit of loss when it comes to how fix it?

I need to return all of these columns with an additional column at the end as TotalTimeMissing

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Updated original post!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what're looking for

```
CREATE TABLE MyData 
(
  StartDate DATETIME, 
  EndDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO MyData VALUES
('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-02 00:25:01'),
('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
('2017-01-02 12:00:09', '2017-01-02 12:00:30'),
('2017-01-01 02:00:00', '2017-01-01 03:30:30'),
('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-03 00:30:30'),
('2017-12-31 23:59:59', '2018-01-01 00:00:01'),
('2017-12-31 23:59:01', '2018-01-01 00:00:01');


SELECT CONCAT(Value / 3600 / 24, 
              ' Days ', 
              RIGHT(CONCAT('00', Value / 3600 % 24), 2), 
              ':', 
              RIGHT(CONCAT('00', Value / 60 % 60), 2), 
              ':',
              RIGHT(CONCAT('00',Value % 3600 % 60), 2)
       ) TimeMissing 
FROM
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(Second, StartDate, EndDate) Value
  FROM MyData
) T(Value);
```

Returns:

```
+-------------------+
|    TimeMissing    |
+-------------------+
| 366 Days 00:25:01 |
| 365 Days 00:00:00 |
| 0 Days 00:00:21   |
| 0 Days 01:30:30   |
| 2 Days 00:30:30   |
| 0 Days 00:00:02   |
| 0 Days 00:01:00   |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: I think you'll be surprised when you see what your code returns for these two `datetimes`: `2017-12-31 23:59:59, 2018-01-01 00:00:01`

Comment: I have updated the original post to be more specific, this isn't quite what I was looking for but is along the right path!

Comment: Thanks for this, I have updated the original post again as this is nearly what I need but I keep getting errors

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the difference in minutes first using the `DATEDIFF` function and then calculate hours and days knowing that 1 hour is 60 minutes and 1 day is 1440 minutes.

Be aware of how the [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 works in SQL Server:

> This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the
>   specified datepart **boundaries** crossed between the specified startdate
>   and enddate.

So,

```
DATEDIFF(day, '2020-01-13 23:59:58', '2020-01-14 00:00:08')
```

will return 1, even though the difference is only few seconds, because the given interval crosses the boundary of a day (midnight).

That's why you should not be using `DATEDIFF(day, ...)` here, but use `DATEDIFF(minute, ...)` or `DATEDIFF(second, ...)` and calculate the number of hours and days based on the total number of elapsed minutes or seconds.

I will use the `CROSS APPLY` to avoid typing the long expression many times.
I also use integer division `/` here which discards the fractional part, e.g. `200 / 60 = 3`.

```
Total days = total minutes / 1440 (discard fractional part)
Total hours = total minutes / 60 (discard fractional part)
```

But, we don't need **total** hours, we need hours that are left extra after the total days, so we need to take mod 24.

```
Hours = Total hours % 24
```

For final minutes we need just the remainder of the minutes after total days and hours, hence

```
Minutes = total minutes mod 60.
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
     dp.LEGACY_ID
    ,dp.SURNAME
    ,dp.FORENAME
    ,mp.DIM_PERSON_ID
    ,mp.MISSING_STATUS
    ,mp.START_DTTM
    ,mp.END_DTTM
    ,dp.LEGACY_ID
    ,STR(DiffMinutes / 1440) + ':' +        -- total days
     STR(DiffMinutes / 60 % 24) + ':' +     -- hours (0 .. 23)
     STR(DiffMinutes % 60) AS TimeMissing   -- minutes (0 .. 59)
FROM 
    MissingPackages AS mp
    JOIN DIM_PERSON AS dp ON mp.DIM_PERSON_ID = dp.DIM_PERSON_ID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, mp.START_DTTM, mp.END_DTTM) AS DiffMinutes
    ) AS A
ORDER BY START_DTTM ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT(DATEDIFF(day, START_DT, END_DT), '-', DATEDIFF(hour, START_DT, END_DT), '-', DATEDIFF(minute, START_DT, END_DT)) AS TimeMissing
```

Comment: Not quite, I'm not looking for: 1-24-1440

I'm looking for: 

start_dttm: 2020-01-01 10:00:00
end_dttm: 2020-01-02 10:00:00

To return: 

24:00:00 as TimeDiff